# How does [::-1] work?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain how does `[::-1]` work? I have read somewhere that it reverses the list, I tried it and it actually works, but I do not know how. What do the 2 colons mean? I could not find anything like this in python documentations.

Also, does someone know the efficiency of this or the underlying algorithm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the slice notation:

```
[start:stop:step]
```

- `start` is the index where you start. If it's omitted, Python assumes you want to start at the beginning.
- `stop` is where you want to stop. If you omit it, Python assumes you want to go until the end.
- `step` is what the `-1` is taking advantage of. `1` is the default value. `2` iterates over every other element. `-1` iterates over all of the elements, but backwards.