# Swapping the pairwise characters of a string in python using applying second in-place slice

Tags: python, slice, reverse

I am new in Python 3. Today while reading about python reverse string using *list* I came to know an in-place slicing technique. The code looks like this:

```
s = input("Enter a string:\n")
''.join([ s[x:x+2][::-1] for x in range(0, len(s), 2) ])
```

I want to know how applying second in-place slice `s[x:x+2][::-1]` working for the pairwise character swap? For other languages, using `[something] [something]` denotes 2D array interpretation. How this is reversing the sliced pair?

Can you please explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996545/how-does-1-work) will answer this question.

Comment: This code doesn't reverse a string. It swaps consecutive pairs of characters.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I get the reversal part `[::-1]` but `s[x:x+2][::-1]` doing the swapping/reversal in-line? Can you please explain?

Comment: @kaya3 , Yes, I meant that. But how does the `s[x:x+2][::-1]` doing the swap/reverse ?

Answer (score 0):

The slicing works like this :

```
[start:stop:step]
```

Now, let's take your code.

```
s[x:x+2][::-1] for x in range(0, len(s), 2)
```

---

```
s[x:x+2]
```

this part takes the string starting with x index till x+1 index. There is no reversing and only slicing.

---

```
[::-1]
```

this part takes the sliced string you got from above and again slices the whole string back [since there is no start and stop, hence the whole string], **but the third parameter tells it how many steps to take for slicing. Here it is `-1`, it means it will take last element and traverse it back which results in a reversed string**.

PS :  Your code doesn't do the reversing of string though as mentioned in comments by @kaya.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm stuck with the second `[::-1]` part. For example, in C++, `[i] [j]` means we are iterating over a 2D array element. Is it a case for python that using `[i] [j]` means it will first iterate over _i_ then _j_ will iterate over the result of _i_?

Comment: no, if you write something like `a[2][3]` in python, it means same as what you have in C++. But when you add `:` part, this is specific to python and would do the slicing of string, from `start`:`stop`